# Tools to write documentation of your code in JS?

Tags: javascript, express, doc

we always use Java doc in java to document our code. 
What tool uses in JS to document code?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use JSDoc, check it out https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/about-getting-started

Comment: See Rob's comment above. We try not to answer questions that really shouldn't be posted here in the first place as it just encourages more of the same.

Comment: Thank you! It was the thing that Im looking for